# Spring Integration: getting the name of the underlying Queue from a Message or MessageChannel

Tags: spring-integration

Given a **MessageChannel** or **Message** object, how is it possible to get from one of them the name of the underlying JMS Queue which the message was received on ?

Here is the scenario:
Several **jms:message-driven-channel-adapter** instances are defined in the xml. The **destination-name** of each adapter uses SEL to receive from different queues.  This SEL is dynamic, and is not possible to know these queue names ahead of time. All channel adapters output to the same internal Spring Integration channel.

I want to add the actual underlying queue name which the message was received on to the header of the message.

The idea is to setup a **ChannelInterceptor** for either the channel-adapters or the internal channel. The **postReceive()** method has both the Message and MessageChannel as arguments. Using either of these, is it possible to get the name of the underlying Queue name which the message came in on?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to extend a bit `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper`:

```
class DestinationJmsHeaderMapper extends DefaultJmsHeaderMapper {
    public Map<String, Object> toHeaders(javax.jms.Message jmsMessage) {
        Map<String, Object> headers = super.toHeaders(jmsMessage);
        headers.put("JMS_DESTINATION", ((Queue) jmsMessage.getJMSDestination()).getQueueName());
    }
}
```

And inject it to your `<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>`s

Comment: Thanks, I have extended DefaultJmsHeaderMaper, am injecting it into the message-driven-adapter, and it is being called. However, from the message passed into the transformer (which the adapter calls), nothing appears to be added to the header. Here is the code
'code'@Component
  public Map<String, Object> toHeaders(Message jmsMessage) {
    Map<String, Object> headers = super.toHeaders(jmsMessage);
    headers.put("SOLACE_TOPIC", ((SolTextMessage) jmsMessage).getJMSDestination().toString());
    return super.toHeaders(jmsMessage);
  }
}'code'

Comment: As it is your class and you receive `SolTextMessage` add a break point to your code and try to investigate a content of incoming JMS message. Maybe desired destination is present in the other property...

Answer (score 0):

This is how we did it:

```
  <int:header-enricher>
     <int:header name="JMS_DESTINATION" expression="payload.JMSDestination.queueName"/>
  </int:header-enricher>
```

It requires `extract-payload="false"` in your `<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>`.

P.S. The answer of Artem is missing the `return` statement (I do not have enough reputations to comment).